# NSButtonCell set button width

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have `NSTableView` on which I create a button for each row dynamically.

```
 NSButtonCell *cell = [[NSButtonCell alloc] init] ;
        [cell setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];
        [cell setBordered:YES];
        [cell setSelectable:TRUE];
        [cell setTarget:self];
        [cell setAction:@selector(openPdfFile:)];
        [cell setTitle:@"Button1"];
```

But I am not able to increase the width so that full button text is visible. Anyone has any idea?
If I remove `[cell setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle];` then I get normal button whose width is fine. But I want to change the style `setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSButtonCell` size will depend on `NSTabeView` Column size. Increase column size.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually, column size is more than button width. Column size is fine. Button width is small for the column which I want to increase.

Comment: Hi, I dont have width problem when I use normal buttoncell. Button width is getting reduced when I set- setBezelStyle:NSRoundedBezelStyle.